# How to get checked radio button with database value in edit blade in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I have value for  `time` column in database. In edit blade i need to show the value with checked radio button.
The code I have:

```
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="slot" class="mb-2">Slot</label>
        <div class="form-check">
           <input class="form-check-input form-check-success" type="radio" name="time" id="time" 
           value={{$appointment->time}}"   required>
           <label class="form-check-label" for="time">{{$appointment->time}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

according to this I am getting only the value with a blank radio button not checked radio button.

Comment: A "checked" radio button requires the ... `checked` attribute.

Comment: Thanks @ brombeer. but User can see previously saved value with checked radio button and user can also check a new value instead of old one . in this case using 'checked' attribute remain checked all the time when selecting a new one

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. You mention new values, do you mean there are more radio buttons? You did not show them ...?  2) You can only select 1 from a set of radio buttons with the same `name` - that's what "radio" means, selecting a new one *UN*selects any previous selection.  3) The `checked` attributre will not remain on the previously selected radio button if you select a new one.  Pls update your question and clarify what it is you are actually asking.